# Holding multiple values in map on a condition

Tags: groovy

I have a record as below(two set of values)

```
record = [ [ name1:'value1', check:0.0,   name2:'value2', name3:'value3' ], 
           [ name1:'value1', check:210.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ],
           [ name1:'value1', check:110.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ] ]
```

is there a way to delete the entry depending on a condition of check. 
if check value is 0, I want to delete that entry and would like to have only the entries which are having check value >=1)

```
[ [ name1:'value1', check:210.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ],
  [ name1:'value1', check:110.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ] ]
```

I tried

```
def recordNew = [:]
if (record.check.intValue() >= 1 ){
    recordNew.put("name1",record.value1)
    recordNew.put("name2",record.value2)
    recordNew.put("name3",record.value3)
}
```

which is holding only one entry

```
[ name1:'value1', check:110.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ]
```

I tried putAll as well, but doesnt seem to serve my purpose

Comment: Your `record` lines are not valid groovy...  Did you paste the right thing?  Did you just mean: `record = [ [ name1:'value1', check:0.0, name2:'value2', name3:'value3'], [name1:'value1', check:210.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3'], [ name1:'value1', check:110.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ] ]`

Comment: Yes Tim, you are right

Comment: Also recordNew should be a list not a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
record = [ [ name1:'value1', check:0.0, name2:'value2', name3:'value3'],
           [ name1:'value1', check:210.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ],
           [ name1:'value1', check:110.0, name2:'value4', name3:'value3' ] ]
```

Then you can just do:

```
recordNew = record.findAll { it.check > 0 }
```

To only keep those entries with `check`> 0

Comment: I forgot to include it.check.intValue() . Thanks Tim